# Facebook style sliding bar for iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to do something like the sliding panel in the iOS Facebook App. Can anyone kindly tell me how that is done or give me pointers ? Thanks.

Comment: Which part do you need help with?  Sliding the panel?  Adding it to the view?

Comment: [This post][1] shows more example about facebook style slideviews.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682110/ios-horizontal-slideview-with-vertical-menu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This 3 examples are great

[JTRevealSideBar](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo)

[ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController)

[DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController)

Answer (score 2):

Besided the 3 options that iYaniv posted, I would suggest you to check another open source implementation: [IIViewDeckController](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/), available in github also. For what I could see, it is a better option.