# iOS horizontal SlideView with vertical menu

Tags: ios, xcode, menu

nowadays lots of iOS iPhone application got a vertical menu and sliding views.

It looks like this:

[image]

I cannot find any examples in Inernet. Need your help, thnx

Comment: It looks like you're showing a view sliding in from the right when the user clicks on the Glavnoye.  Is that what you want?

Comment: something like this. any examples?

Comment: For iOS8, iOS7 and Swift:

Answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532746/1887635

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For iPhone you can use this one : [ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/alecgorge/ZUUIRevealController)

Comment: yeah! i found it 2 mins ago ) thnx

Answer (score 29):

I found it!

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController     // ------------active as of Sept, 2014

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu    //------------ active Sept, 2014

https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu       // Deprecated

https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController   // 3 years

https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController      // link broken

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck         // 2 years old

https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController  // 3 years old

https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo  // discontinued

Comment: MFSideMenu seemed to be the most natural of these for me to use. The other ones don't seem to follow a standard navigation controller flow. I was able to drop this into my existing navigationcontroller driven app with minimal rework.

Comment: @Eugene: I have subclassed my navigationcontroller and placed the MFSideMenu initialisation code inside it and it works pretty fine. But When I introduced it with a modal segue (from a login screen) the menu button doesn't work anymore. Did you experience anything like that?

Comment: You can find an example here http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9409/screenshot20121230at183.png
if I set as entry point the login page (the one with the button) it doesn't work, if I move the entry point to the NavigationController it works.

Comment: @Claus yes, i got same issue ((

Comment: Add MMDrawerController to the list as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Its explained here pretty much properly step by step those who are interested in doing so without using customised menus can check here :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

Answer (score 2):

I made a video (3 parts) on youtube on how to make a sliding menu like the on you are looking for. I show you how to set up the project and get everything linked up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

This uses the ECSlidingViewController, and the setup is a little different than you might expect but it works really well and is very smooth.

I have tested it with navigationcontroller as well so hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a standard UITableView, which, when you click on a row, pushes another view controller's view onto the screen (but you would usually have a disclosure indicator, a ">", not a check mark in the row).

Apple has an example in the docs called TheElements.  Have a look at that one and see if that's something like what you want. When you click on an element name in the table it slides another view with more information about that element over the table.