# How to make specific table?

Tags: ios, animation

How can I make table like on the picture?
I need a large (main) part of the screen there is a table with menus, and to a lesser strip right could put another view (and pass it on to swipe), but part of this kind should be visible on most (main) part of the screen. I need some sort of an example or sample, I could not find anything similar in the search.

I can not post image, but I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Does https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ios+swipe+menu help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That control is often called a [side menu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=side+menu) or [hamburger menu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hamburger+menu) and there are lots of examples and pre-made libraries around for it.

Answer (score 0):

Look this: [left menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682110/ios-horizontal-slideview-with-vertical-menu). I used [ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController)