# Facebook like slideing drawer in iPhone, iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to make sliding drawer like Facebook for iOS. I have try it with navigation and fragments but its didn't work properly. i am getting troubles in touch events for right to left sliding. 
its didn't work with gesture for touch for left and right sliding.
Help me if you have any idea about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS horizontal SlideView with vertical menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682110/ios-horizontal-slideview-with-vertical-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my research i have found following link for sample code of SW reveal sliding drawer.

it's work perfectly for me please find the below link for Facebook like sliding

### Android

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.git

https://github.com/appersonlabs/MASlidingMenu

### iOS

https://github.com/jamztang/JTRevealSidebarDemo

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

Answer (score 3):

There are many libraries to implement this. Here are some for you

Please check below links. It may help you

1. [how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path)
2. [How To Add a Slide-out Sidebar Menu in Your Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)
3. [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController)
4. [iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu)
5. [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController)

Answer (score 1):

i frequently use[this](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) control. very easy to implement

```
    UIViewController * leftDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController * center = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController * rightDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

MMDrawerController * drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                                       initWithCenterViewController:center
                                           leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer
                                           rightDrawerViewController:rightDrawer];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a tutorial for a reference: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/