# Slide Sidebar Menu IOS 8 Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

Is there a way to implement Slide Sidebar Menu (Like Facebook app) in IOS Swift without any third party library? I look for solutions but I only founded this feature implemented in Objective-C.

Comment: Research the Swift language and implement the solutions for Objective-C in swift.

Comment: were u able to implement it?

Comment: @68cherries I just tried with AMSlideout, written in obj c. but could not embed it on swift. i'm looking for slide / swipe out navigator in swift

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you can start form UISplitViewController which was drastically updated in iOS8. Watch sessions [View Controller Advancements in iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=214) and [Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=216)  for details. They provide [code example from second session](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AdaptivePhotos/Introduction/Intro.html) (but not form first one :/). At this point it feels natural for me to make this kind of UI based on split view controller in iOS8.

Update: It looks like not all API they talking about are landed yet. In current beta4 mentioned in video condensesBarsOnSwipe is not presented, for example.

Comment: the sidebar only float show up with ipad. with iphone, it just look like navigation, back + forward only. can it possible to get it float?

Comment: @TomSawyer it is, check video I linked on above. You can change controller behavior in many ways. Use size classes to  make it think it is not in compact.

Comment: For those wanting to implement a sidebar on iphone using UISplitViewController, the solution starts at 14:21 in the "View Controller Advancements in iOS8" link above.

Answer (score 16):

> **Update**: Please consider using my updated answer rather than this one. There's a lot of edge cases with the Scrollview/Container View approach that can be avoided by using Custom View Controller Transitions instead.

I looked all over the place for a Swift menu solution that didn't require a library. Ended up creating a tutorial of my own, which is fairly similar to Fengson's approach:

[image]

Here are some of the main points:

- Create a `scrollview` which will handle the menu sliding motion, along with the pan gesture
- Put two `container` views side by side, inside the `scrollview`. Containers allow you to embed top level controllers.
- On the `scrollview`, set `paging enabled` but disable `bounces`. This will coerce the slideout into an open or closed state
- `embed` a `UITableViewController` in the left container
- `embed` a `UITabBarController` in the right container
- On the right `container`, add a runtime attribute `layer.shadowOpacity` of 0.8. This gives you a free shadow separator without any code.
- Add a menu button. You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to communicate with the `scrollview`
- For the secret ingredient: use `scrollView.setContentOffset.x` to take care of the actual opening and closing of the menu

Here's a working example project of a tab bar application with a left slideout menu, including screenshots and instructions.

https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/LeftSlideoutMenu

Along with a more generic explanation of how it works:

http://www.thorntech.com/2015/06/want-to-implement-a-slideout-menu-in-your-swift-app-heres-how/

Comment: definitely initeresting approach, but the main problem - is a bit un-natural animation. I would expect main view on close  to "cover" menu, not to "push"

Comment: @Robert Chen suppose on tap of any option from the menu i want to show different view controller and i also want the menu to be present on that view controller... How do we achieve this using this technique . Do we need to add the 2 container views on all such view controllers ?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Do you mean that you want to leave the menu open when pushing a view controller?  I suppose you could refrain from calling the close menu method when selecting that item.

Or, are you asking if you could push a view controller that has the menu embedded inside?  Is there a screenshot of another app that does something similar?

Comment: @RobertChen Yes i meant a view controller that has the menu embedded inside. Example:- For the current view controller(say A) we have two  container views within a scroll view and on click of menu we scroll the x axis of scroll view and display the menu , now if i click on another option from a menu it should show a different view controller(say B) with a menu embedded in it. Will i have to add a scroll view and container view in the second view controller (B) as well?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Thanks for elaborating.  So, it sounds like you want to replace whatever is in the right container rather than pushing a child page that you would need to swipe back from.  This way, you can change the page using the left menu, but always have the left menu available.  If this is the case, maybe you could use the same setup, but set the Tab Bar Controller's Tab Bar to `Hidden`.  Then wire the left menu selection to switch between tabs.  But with the tab bar hidden, it gives the illusion that you're switching pages in-place.  If I'm off track, please let me know.

Answer (score 10):

I think using Custom View Controller Transitions is a solid approach for making slideout menus:

- You can customize the animation.
- The transition is interactive, so you can drag to progress forward and backward. The transition always finishes or rolls back, and never gets stuck in-between states.
- You use Pan Gestures and Screen Edge Pan Gestures to drive the interaction. This means you can place them strategically to minimize conflict with horizontally gestured content.
- You don't have to resort to Container Views. This means your app architecture is flatter, and you can use protocol-delegate instead of NSNotifications.
- There's only one ViewController active at a time. Snapshots are used to give the illusion that there's a second VC on the screen.

[image: interactive slide out animated GIF]

Custom View Controller Transitions are difficult to learn at first (they were for me, at least). I wrote a [blog post](http://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/ios-tutorial-make-interactive-slide-menu-swift/) on how to create an interactive slideout menu, and tried my best to make it as easy to understand as possible.

You can also jump straight into the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/InteractiveSlideOutMenu).

At a very high level, this is how it works:

1. You open the slideout menu as a modal.
2. You create custom animations for the present and dismiss transitions using the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. You use a snapshot to represent the main view controller during animations.
3. You create Pan Gesture Recognizers to present/dismiss the modal interactively.
4. You wire the Pan Gesture events to a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` object to keep the transition in sync with the user's movements.
5. The presenting controller adopts the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol and wires up all the custom animations and interactive transitions.

I actually have a previous answer on this thread that uses a Scrollview / Container View. This approach is OK for a prototype, but runs into a lot of edge cases and bugs when making your app production ready. Spending every week responding to blog comments and fixing edge cases is what motivated me to write a second blog post on the subject.

Answer (score 9):

Slide side bar menus for iOS7 and iOS8, Swift coded.

If you want it at **NavigationController level** (it means, for al View controllers behind it):

https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu

If you want it just in one **ViewController**:

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaLiZgUK2T0

Source-code: http://goo.gl/ULWxJh

In this case, for iOS7 compatibility, just add this "if" condition where the "Add blur view" comment is placed, like this:

```
if (NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil) {        
    // Add blur view
    let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
    blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
    sideBarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another SideMenu library I made to add to the mix: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu.

> Simple side menu control for iOS in Swift inspired by Facebook. Right
> and Left sides. No coding required.
>
> - **It can be implemented in storyboard without a single line of code.**
> - Four standard animation styles to choose from (even parallax if you want to get weird).
> - Highly customizable without needing to write tons of custom code.
> - Supports continuous swiping between side menus on boths sides in a single gesture.
> - Global menu configuration. Set-up once and be done for all screens.
> - Menus can be presented and dismissed the same as any other View Controller since this control uses custom transitions.
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi, @jonkykong I am using your sidepanel. It works really fine.
I just want to customise the width of the sidepanel dynamically clicking on the menu item.Kindly tell me how should I do that?

I will post the screen if the question is not clear.

Comment: Hi @jonkykong, I implemented your SideMenu library in my swift project, here I implemented through storyboard. Here in by default the SideMenuPresentStyle is Slide In + Out. But I need Slide In. How can I implement that. Can I able to do this through storyboard?

Comment: how to do parallax effect ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small example of how I do it, this drawer control has uiviewcontrollers for left, center, and right.  This one works like the Slack IPad app where either one side or the other is open.

```
/*
 To use simply instantiate SlidingDrawerController as your root view in your AppDelegate, or in the
 StoryBoard.
 Once SlidingDrawerController is instantiated, set the drawerSize of the SlidingDrawerController,
 and its leftViewControllerIdentifier, centerViewControllerIdentifier, and
 rightViewControllerIdentifier to the Storyboard Identifier of the UIViewController
 you want in the different locations.
 */

class SlidingDrawerController: UIViewController {
    var drawerSize:CGFloat = 4.0
    var leftViewControllerIdentifier:String = "leftViewController"
    var centerViewControllerIdentifier:String = "centerViewController"
    var rightViewControllerIdentifier:String = "rightViewController"

    enum Drawers {
        case left
        case right
    }

    private var _leftViewController:UIViewController?
    var leftViewController:UIViewController {
        get{
            if let vc = _leftViewController {
                return vc;
            }
            return UIViewController();
        }
    }
    private var _centerViewController:UIViewController?
    var centerViewController:UIViewController {
        get{
            if let vc = _centerViewController {
                return vc;
            }
            return UIViewController();
        }
    }
    private var _rightViewController:UIViewController?
    var rightViewController:UIViewController {
        get{
            if let vc = _rightViewController {
                return vc;
            }
            return UIViewController();
        }
    }

    static let SlidingDrawerOpenLeft = 1
    static let SlidingDrawerOpenRight = 2
    var openSide:SlidingDrawerController.Drawers {
        get{
            return _openSide;
        }
    }
    private var _openSide = SlidingDrawerController.Drawers.left

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Instantiate VC's with storyboard ID's
        self._leftViewController = self.instantiateViewControllers(storyboardID: self.leftViewControllerIdentifier)
        self._centerViewController = self.instantiateViewControllers(storyboardID: self.centerViewControllerIdentifier)
        self._rightViewController = self.instantiateViewControllers(storyboardID: self.rightViewControllerIdentifier)

        self.drawDrawers(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)

        self.view.addSubview(self.leftViewController.view)
        self.view.addSubview(self.centerViewController.view)
        self.view.addSubview(self.rightViewController.view)
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: self.view, animation: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            // This is for beginning of transition
            self.drawDrawers(size: size)
        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            // This is for after transition has completed.
        })

    }

    // MARK: - Drawing View

    func drawDrawers(size:CGSize) {
        // Calculate Center View's Size
        let centerWidth = (size.width/drawerSize) * (drawerSize - 1)
        // Left Drawer
        self.leftViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width/self.drawerSize, height: size.height)

        // Center Drawer
        self.centerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.leftViewController.view.frame.width, y: 0.0, width: centerWidth, height: size.height)

        // Right Drawer
        self.rightViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.centerViewController.view.frame.origin.x + self.centerViewController.view.frame.size.width, y: 0.0, width: size.width/self.drawerSize, height: size.height)

        // Capture the Swipes
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeRightAction(rec:)))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        centerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeLeftAction(rec:)))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        centerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        openDrawer(openSide)
    }

    // MARK: - Open Drawers
    func openDrawer(_ side:Drawers) {
        self._openSide = side
        var rect:CGRect
        switch side{
        case .left:
            rect = CGRect(
                x: 0.0,
                y: 0.0,
                width: self.view.bounds.width,
                height: self.view.bounds.height
            )
        case .right:
            rect = CGRect(
                x: self.view.bounds.origin.x - self.leftViewController.view.bounds.size.width,
                y: 0.0,
                width: self.view.bounds.width,
                height: self.view.bounds.height
            )
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:
            { () -> Void in
                // move views here
                self.view.frame = rect
        }, completion:
            { finished in
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Swipe Handling

    @objc func swipeRightAction(rec: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        self.openDrawer(.left)
    }

    @objc func swipeLeftAction(rec:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        self.openDrawer(.right)
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    func instantiateViewControllers(storyboardID: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(storyboardID)")

    }
}
```

Source [here](https://github.com/popmedic/ios-slidingdrawer).

Image [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/popmedic/ios-slidingdrawer/master/sliding-drawer-storyboard.png).

Video [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/popmedic/ios-slidingdrawer/master/sliding-drawer.mp4).

Comment: The code looked easy enough, but since I couldn't really imagine how it would look like I gave it a try. This is what I ended up with, so that when anyonce else doesn't have to figure out if this is what they're looking for: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9CH5I.png

Comment: @Neejoh thank you and sorry I did not add that.  I guess a gist would have worked better.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented it in 2 ways.
First using `Scroll View` and second using `Container Views`.

You can have `TableViewController` acting as a Menu in one container and a `TabBarController` with hidden tabs in a second container. Pressing a `Cell` in a Table View moves you to a n-th tab in Tab Bar.

All you have to do is animate the top container right on button click or a gesture. It then may look like this:

[image]

What is neat is that you can then easily add cool effects such as animating UIView using spring damping by using built-in methods to give it realistic bouncy effect. You can also add shadow to your main View (not added in the picture) to make it look like a page above the menu.