# How to create Sidebar menu in IOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am searching for some suggestions how to create a *sidebar menu* in *swift* **not** in **storyboard** or **xib** only.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift. Very simple to set up in storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe you can start form UISplitViewController which was
>   drastically updated in iOS8. Watch sessions [View Controller
>   Advancements in
>   iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=214) and
>   [Building Adaptive Apps with
>   UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=216) for
>   details. They provide [code example from second
>   session](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AdaptivePhotos/Introduction/Intro.html)
>   (but not form first one :/). At this point it feels natural for me to
>   make this kind of UI based on split view controller in iOS8.

checkout: [Slide Sidebar Menu IOS 8 Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123004/slide-sidebar-menu-ios-8-swift/24797841#24797841)

You can also checkout this Tutorial:
 http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

It's a great Tutorial with an example.

Comment: The first paragraph is a verbatim copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24797841/1187415 without attribution, this is considered as plagiarism.

Comment: I forgot it. I'm sorry about this. I have Edit it.

Answer (score 1):

work for me...

I created a new view controller as "MenuViewController", and two customs segues class.

The first class to open and the second to close the menu.

TO OPEN THE MENU:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {

let src = self.source as UIViewController
let dst = self.destination as UIViewController

src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
},
                           completion: { finished in
                            src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
)

}

}
```

TO CLOSE THE MENU:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {

let src = self.source as UIViewController
let dst = self.destination as UIViewController

src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, belowSubview: src.view)
src.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                           animations: {
                            src.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)
},
                           completion: { finished in
                            src.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
)
}
}
```

This tutorial is for a menu from left to right, but if you want in the opposite direction, change :

```
-src.view.frame.size.width
```

to:

```
src.view.frame.size.width
```

I hope it helped you...