# Create navigation drawer by presenting controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation-drawer

I have crate one demo navigation drawer by pre-setting a controller with custom animation from left to right. And when we dismiss the controller we apply animation from right to left. It works though but the drawer animation does not look as good as native android drawer. So can you tell me what is the best way to achieve this. Although I don't want to depend upon any third party for this functionality.

```
@IBAction func actionMenu(_ sender: Any) {

        let controler:DrawerController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerController")
        as! DrawerController
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        present(controler, animated: false) {
            controler.drawerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            controler.drawerView.alpha = 0.6
        }
    }
```

Below is storyboard screenshot
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you only want it to slide in and out animatedly like in android?

Comment: Check answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123004/slide-sidebar-menu-ios-8-swift

Comment: Yes shadow and animation to be same

Answer (score 4):

If you want to achieve this without using any third-arty lib it is achievable by this approach.

1. Add a container view in  MainViewController .
2. Add Side TableViewController to container view using segue
3. Set the width of Container view as needed.
4. Add constraints to container view leading, top, bottom and constant width.
5. Create outlet of trailing constraint in view and toggle its constant from MainViewController value minus Width value to hide and 0 to show.

** MainViewController**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func openView(_ sender: Any) {
        if leadingConstraint.constant == -250{
            leadingConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        else{
            leadingConstraint.constant = -250
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

**SlideTableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SlideTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var dataItems: [String] = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabelView.delegate = self
        tabelView.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

**Result**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking another ViewController, you can take **.xib** of UIView as your Navigation drawer and apply custom animation for presenting this UIView from left to right by changing it's X-coordinate and it's frame.

Comment: should I add it on window or current view ?

Comment: you have to add it on current top view

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the view contorller with freeform size and present the controller with

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
yourContorller.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```