# sliding UI panels on iOS but where it slides out of another panel (i.e. not where the main window is frozen and slides out)

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have done some iOS dev work, though mostly for my own edification and with static and ugly UI. I've been tasked with making a dynamic UI for an app, and the spec calls for sliding panels. The basic layout is:

[Left Panel][Viewing Panel][Right Panel]

If you click on a button on the Left Panel, a second panel with more buttons is supposed to slide out, looking something like:

[Left Panel][Second Left Panel][Smaller Viewing Panel][Right Panel]

The buttons have to be dynamic and the UI needs to be skinned as well. Are there examples/guides on building this kind of UI in iOS? I've seen posts about the other kind of sliding panel app (a la FaceBook):

[Facebook style sliding bar for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562134/facebook-style-sliding-bar-for-ios-app)

But that's not exactly what I need, does anyone know of references/examples for the kind of UI I'm talking about?

Thanks!

Comment: Go on https://www.cocoacontrols.com and download some of those. You'll probably be able to copy an implementation there or maybe even extend one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of libraries that people have written to accomplish something like this. I recently used [ECSidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController), but a quick search found [JASidePanels](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels), [PKRevealController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pkrevealcontroller), and [MFSideMenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mfsidemenu). All implement a sliding side menu, and while i'm not sure what you're describing with the "second panel with more buttons" these solutions could likely be nested to achieve that. JASidePanel appears to haveh built in stuff for that as well.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I've perhaps not been clear. The left and right sections are the same, and the left section spawns a slide out panel. Perhaps I can use the examples to implement that.